# Winforms RadPageView find control

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, telerik, tabcontrol

I have nested controls inside RadPageView control on a Winform application. RadPageView has a child RadPageViewPage. These two controls are on the form however a tab control and inside that tab control some other controls are added dynamically. How can I find and change the value of the Textbox inside the dynamically generated tab control on a click of the button.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TabControl tb = new TabControl();
        tb.Width = 500;
        TabPage tp = new TabPage("Tab 1");

        Label lb = new Label();
        lb.Text = "Test";
        lb.Location = new Point(10, 10);

        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.Text = "Textbox";
        txt.Location = new Point(200, 10);

        tp.Controls.Add(lb);
        tp.Controls.Add(txt);

        tb.Controls.Add(tp);

        radPageViewPage1.Controls.Add(tb);


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the controls ids, then accessing them through the `FindControl()` method?

Comment: It is a winforms application. It does not have id attribute.

Comment: RIght, I meant name. It's been a long day. I think `this.Controls.Find()` with the name of the control would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this example over the internet and its working perfectly.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TabControl tb = new TabControl();
        tb.Width = 500;
        TabPage tp = new TabPage("Tab 1");

        Label lb = new Label();
        lb.Text = "Test";
        lb.Name = "lblTest";
        lb.Location = new Point(10, 10);

        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.Text = "Textbox";
        txt.Name = "txtName";
        txt.Location = new Point(200, 10);

        tp.Controls.Add(lb);
        tp.Controls.Add(txt);

        tb.Controls.Add(tp);

        radPageViewPage1.Controls.Add(tb);


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var crl = FindControl("txtName");
        MessageBox.Show(crl.Text);
    }

    Control FindControl(string target)
    {
        return FindControl(this, target);
    }

    static Control FindControl(Control root, string target)
    {
        if (root.Name.Equals(target))
            return root;
        for (var i = 0; i < root.Controls.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (root.Controls[i].Name.Equals(target))
                return root.Controls[i];
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < root.Controls.Count; ++i)
        {
            Control result;
            for (var k = 0; k < root.Controls[i].Controls.Count; ++k)
            {
                result = FindControl(root.Controls[i].Controls[k], target);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```